# Extend/retract speed of linear actuators

Tags: technic, piece-information

I am trying to find out if the linear actuators (small, large and XL) have a fixed number of rotations on the bottom axle connector in order to extend them fully?

I am guessing the small LA will take fewer turns?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's inside a linear actuator?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/17678/whats-inside-a-linear-actuator)

Comment: Not really, but the video added does so thanks one and all

Comment: I voted to leave this question open, I think LA's are complicated/interesting enough to have multiple (in my opinion unrelated) questions about them

Answer (score 9):

I found Sariels video here helpful:

[image]
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A23yh-enhyI

Sariel states that all 3 LA's extend and retract at the same speed.
Several sources state that the L linear actuator takes 26 revolutions to extend to its full 5 studs, so the small LA will take 15.6 revolutions to extend to its full 3 studs and the new XL linear actuator will take 41.6 revolutions to extend to its full 8 studs.

Comment: Thanks that's great info

Comment: Glad they all seam to be 5.2 rotations per stud